# file Upload with ajax not working properly on firefox

Tags: ajax, yii2

i have the below code to upload file to server via ajax and it seems to work as expected on IE 10 and chrome but not working on firefox browser, is there any way to work around this problem? below is the code and the output on all the major browsers

```
$('input.upload').on('change', function(event){
         files = event.target.files[0];
         uploadFiles(event);
          });
function uploadFiles(event)
{
      event.stopPropagation(); 
    event.preventDefault(); 
            var form_data = new FormData();                  
              form_data.append('file', files);
              //console.log(form_data);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'uploads.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: form_data,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'text',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false, //
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
            if(typeof data.error === 'undefined')
            {
                console.log(data);
            }
            else
            {
                console.log('ERRORS: ' + data.error);
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            console.log('ERRORS: ' + textStatus);
        }
    });
}
```

And in my contoller i have the below code:

```
public function actionUpload()
{
$upload = new Upload();
$model = new Photos();
$fileName = 'file';


if (isset($_FILES[$fileName])) {
    $upload->image =     \yii\web\UploadedFile::getInstanceByName($fileName);
    $file = $upload->image;
            if ($upload->upload()) {
        //Now save file data to database
        $model->photo1 = $upload->fileDirectory;

        if($model->save()){
           echo \yii\helpers\Json::encode($file); 
        }

    }
}

return false;
}
```

On google chrome and IE browser the console.log(data) of the success method in ajax output the following which is correct

```
{"name":"mmexport1370251431731.jpg","tempName":"/tmp/php0UCw4B","type":"image/jpeg","size":36185,"error":0}
```

On firefox browser the console.log(data) of the success method in ajax output the following.only the file name is return and other file attribute return empty string and error return 1

```
{"name":"mmexport1370251431731.jpg","tempName":"","type":"","size":0,"error":1}
```